# iOS how to solve "you have already purchased this item would you like to buy it again" issue with Firebase analytics

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, in-app-purchase, storekit

I implemented Google admob with Firebase integration for the analytics. I want to get the user to pay in order to remove the ads. The code for this works but some issues.

I get the message **"You have already purchased this item would you like to buy it again"** even if the user is purchasing it for the first time.

The ads were able to be removed eventually but the message above is confusing to the user.

1) I read online that the issue can be resolved if I place this code

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
```

before the Firebase statement in the AppDelegate

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

But I cannot compile the code if `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)` this is the AppDelegate class.

2) I commented out `FirebaseApp.configure()` after reading that Firebase also add its own TransactionObserver. But this did not work either.

3) I placed `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)` in the GameScene class in the `sceneDidLoad()` function but this did not solve the problem.

4) I have `queue.finishTransaction(transaction)` in the func paymentQueue function for each of the **SKPaymentTransactionState** state.

Update with code used in the sandbox app:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    btnRemoveBannerAds.isEnabled = false
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    getPurchaseInfo()

}

@IBAction func removeBannerAds(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let skPayment = SKPayment(product: skProduct!)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(skPayment)

}


extension PurchaseViewController : SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

func getPurchaseInfo() {

    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {

        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: NSSet(objects: self.productID) as! Set<String>) // dont understand this?
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()

    } else {

        print("In App purchase not enabled")
    }

}

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

    var products = response.products

    if products.count == 0 {

        print("Product not found")

    } else {

        skProduct = products[0]
        print("product is \(String(describing: skProduct))")

        btnRemoveBannerAds.isEnabled = true

    }

    let invalids = response.invalidProductIdentifiers

    for product in invalids {

        print("Product not found \(product)")

    }

}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    for transaction in transactions {

        switch transaction.transactionState {

        case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchased:

            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

            btnRemoveBannerAds.isEnabled = false

            userPref.setValue(true, forKey: "AdRemovalPurchase")
            userPref.synchronize()

        case SKPaymentTransactionState.restored:

            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

            btnRemoveBannerAds.isEnabled = false

            userPref.setValue(true, forKey: "AdRemovalPurchase")
            userPref.synchronize()

        case SKPaymentTransactionState.failed:

            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

            btnRemoveBannerAds.isEnabled = false

        default:

            break

        }

    }

}
```

}

Please advise how to implement this. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is a Firebase issue. This seems to be more of an issue with the way you've implemented StoreKit. Can you maybe rephrase your question and include the relevant code?

Comment: Updated with code. Thanks.